Is it possible to dynamically add a service to the ConfigureServices section of Startup.cs?
I am using a great SAML 2.0 library called ITFoxTec in my .Net Core 2.1 Web Application.
I have everything setup based on the multiple examples and tutorials available on the web.
I have a Login landing page where the user can either press a Local Login button or a SAML Login button.
One of the pieces of code needed is this line in the Startup.cs class in the ConfigureServices section:
// ** ITFoxTec SAML(services.AddSaml2())
services.AddSaml2();

services.AddMvc();
var builder = CompositionRoot.MakeContainerBuilder(RunConfig);
builder.Populate(services);
ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

And then in my Configure section, I have this:
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        "spa-fallback",
        "{*clientRoute}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        new { clientRoute = new SpaRouteConstraint("clientRoute") },
                null
    );
});

// ** ITFoxTec SAML (app.UseSaml2())
app.UseSaml2();

However, when I put that in(services.AddSaml2()) and run the web app, it is directing me to the IdP immediately...bypassing my Login page.
If I leave it out, the app works fine and goes to my Login page.
However, with it out, and I click the SAML Login Button, the IdP returns an error that just says Bad Request 400.
So is there a way to add services.AddSaml2(); dynamically when I click the "SAML Login" button?
